# Empty response from Google Vision API with an image stored in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use the cloud vision API and I am able to make a successful request, but my response comes back empty, even with the test image provided on the API docs.

Request Body:

```
const imagePath = `gs://[bucket_name]/faulkner.jpg`;
const requestObject = {
  requests: [
    {
      image: {
        source: {
          gcsImageUri: imagePath
        }
      },
      features:[
        {
          type: 'LABEL_DETECTION',
          maxResults: 100
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

[faulkner.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cFiV.jpg)

Response Body:

```
{
  "responses": [{}]
}
```

I have even tried using the cloud API console and copy the request fields, and that too does not work

```
const apiKey = 'myAPIKey';
const fields = `fields=responses(labelAnnotations)&`;
const visionAPI = `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?${fields}key=${apiKey}`;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this exact issue, this is what worked for me...

1. You do not need OAuth, just an API key.

This is what I was doing wrong...

In my HTTP call I needed to wrap my request in a new object literal as in

```
{data: requestBody }
```

To clarify,

```
// My old call
HTTP.call("POST", "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=myAPIKey", requestBody, myCallback);

// To my new call
HTTP.call("POST", "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=myAPIKey", {data: requestBody}, myCallback);

// reqeustBody example

{
  "requests":
    [
      {
        "features":
          [
            {
              "type": "LABEL_DETECTION"
            } 
          ],
        "image":
          {
            "source":
              {
                "gcsImageUri": "gs://myBucketNameHere/myDemoImageNameHere.jpg"
              }
          }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**NOTE:** A few things that need to be done.

1. Image is in your Google Cloud Platform Storage Bucket.
2. The image name is exact in the call as it is in storage.
3. The image must have something to detect i.e. if using FACE_DETECTION the image must have a human face.
4. The image in Google Cloud Platform Storage **MUST** be checked to **Share publicly**.

I am using the very same call above with my image named **demo-image.jpg** and everything works now that I wrapped the requestBody.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing OAuth2 with the appropriate token. For using Vision API with gCS Images, we cannot just use the API Key.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the request using an oauth2 access key? There's a quick-and-dirty way to test this on the command line if you have the [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) tool:

- [Create and download](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/getting-started#setting_up_a_service_account) a [service account json key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_)
- Set `gcloud` to use that service account:

  ```
  gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <service-account-file.json>
  ```
- Get an access token using `gcloud auth print-access-token` and perform a `curl` request with it:

  ```
  curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
      -H "content-type: application/json" \
      --data-binary '{"requests": [{"image": {"source": {"gcs_image_uri": "gs://your-bucket/your-object.jpg"}}, "features":  [{"type": "LABEL_DETECTION", "maxResults": 100}]}]}' \
      "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json"
  ```

For production use, though, you'll want to explicitly use the [oauth2 flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices) to get your access tokens, since they're short-lived and require refreshing.